# List of dict unique combination Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have big data For the visualization purpose, This is the example list of dict as,

**Input :**

```
a = [{'e1': 'a','e2': 'b'}, {'e1': 'b','e2': 'a'}, {'e1': 'a','e2': 'c'} ]
```

**Output :**

```
a = [{'e1': 'a','e2': 'b'}, {'e1': 'a','e2': 'c'}]
```

Detail:
If `{'e1': 'a','e2': 'b'}` and `{'e1': 'b','e2': 'a'}` are pointing to each others value then I want this as unique `{'e1': 'a','e2': 'b'}`.

So basically e1 is source and e2 is target. if any connection exists between source and target should be unique. Here already A connected to B then it should not consider B connected to A.

Comment: Example does not match your detail section

Comment: e1 and e2 keys are not sharing the same values in either of the other 2 dictionaries...

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve? Kindly add a detailed explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Combination of dict {'e1': 'a','e2': 'b'} and {'e1': 'b','e2': 'a'} are pointing each other

Comment: @Kjjassy they are not the same at all. In the first `e1` has a value of `a` and in the second dict it is `b`

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov here e1 has value a and e2 has value b. Another one e1 has b and e2 has a. So the second one is opposite to e1. Then it should take the unique one only.

Comment: @ShikharChauhan Basically e1 is source and e2 is target. So if any connection exists between source and target should be unique. Here already A connected to B then it should not consider B connected to A.

Comment: I think you need to reword your explanation what you're trying to achieve. Also some background explanation could be useful, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Are there always only going to be two items per dictionary, or could there be more?

Comment: What would you use a dictionary for this? If your dictionaries all have the same key use tuples instead.

Comment: @PabloArias I didn't got your que. but As i said for Visualization i am showing source A and Target B for this i need to show link which is common value of pointing each other objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this one

```
from itertools import groupby
[j.next() for i , j in groupby(a, lambda x: sorted(x.values()))
```

output:

```
[{'e1': 'a', 'e2': 'b'}, {'e1': 'a', 'e2': 'c'}]
```

Comment: Careful, this will only work if the duplicates are contiguous in the list, for example the list:
(a,b)(c,d)(b,a) 
will not be filtered by groupby

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> dup_checker, output_a = [], []
>>> for dict_element in a:
       element_values = dict_element.values()
       element_values.sort()
       if  element_values not in dup_checker:
           output_a.append(dict_element)
           dup_checker.append(element_values)

>>> output_a
[{'e1': 'a', 'e2': 'b'}, {'e1': 'a', 'e2': 'c'}]
```

sort the dict element values and create a dup_checker to track.

Comment: Nice answer. As an optimization you could make dup_checker a set instead of a list.